# IBM Mobilefirst with katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications plugin custom sound is not playing on device

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I have integrated the Cordova local-notification plugin on IBM mobile-first Hybrid application. Local notifications are working fine, but custom sound is not playing. I have copied the custom sound in the android raw folder, even I have created the common sounds folder [created the common sounds folder ][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrvE7.png[android raw folder copied the audio file][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWzM.png

Here is my local notification schedule method properties 
1)

```
localnotification.schedule({
        id: 11,
        text: "Wake up!",
        sound: "file://audio.mp3",
        title: "Meeting in 3 minutes!",
        at: _5_sec_from_now,
        every: "day"
    });
```

I have even tried following paths to play the audio file, but not playing the audio, but notification display in silent mood

```
1)sound:"file://audio.mp3",
2)sound:"android.resource://com.Alarm/raw/audio.mp3"
3)sound:"file://android_res/raw/audio.mp3"
4)sound:"file://sounds/audio.mp3"
5)sound:"file://android_asset/www/default/sounds/audio.mp3"
```

Any help really appreciated

Comment: MFP 8.0? Or another version?

Comment: MFP version 7.1

Comment: have you sorted it out ?
For a normal server pushed notification the sound file path is the same as a local notification ?